# Event Handling for Pie Chart

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have created a javafx pie chart and want to do something when the user clicks on a slice of the pie. I am following this tutorial:

```
for (final PieChart.Data data : chart.getData()) {
data.getNode().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            caption.setTranslateX(e.getSceneX());
            caption.setTranslateY(e.getSceneY());
            caption.setText(String.valueOf(data.getPieValue()) + "%");
         }
    });
```

I am getting these error warnings prior to compile:
On the ".addEventHandler"

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method addEventHandler(EventType<T>, EventHandler<?
superT>) of   type Node is not applicable for the arguments (Integer, new
EventHandler<MouseEvent>  (){}). The inferred type MouseEvent&Event is not a valid 
substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Event>
```

On the "EventHandler"

```
Bound mismatch: The type MouseEvent is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  
<T extends Event> of the type EventHandler<T>
```

Does anyone have any insights into why I am getting these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addEventHandler()` method takes two parameters: one of type `T`, and one that has a super class `T`. You gave it an `EventHandler` and an `Integer`. Since `Integer` is not a super class of `EventHandler`, you get an exception.

My guess is that you're accidentally using [Java SE's MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_PRESSED) instead of [Java FX's MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_PRESSED).

Comment: Yes, eclipse told me as much. Thank you for elaborating though.

Answer (score 1):

I made the following changes to fix the problem, th is is javafx specific.

```
for (final PieChart.Data data : chart.getData()) {
data.getNode().addEventHandler(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent e) {
     }
});
```